# Is the function $\frac{\operatorname{Harmonic}(x)}{\operatorname{Airy}(x)}$ a convex function for real numbers $0<x<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, harmonic-numbers, airy-functions

For real numbers $0\leq x\leq 1$, I know how to exlore some aspects of the graph ( I was playing with Wolfram Alpha online calculator about its plot, see next paragraph) of the function $$f(x)=\frac{H_x}{\operatorname{Ai}(x)},$$ where $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ is the Airy function, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html) and $H_x$ is the harmonic number.

The code in Wolfram Language is

`plot Harmonic(x)/Airy(x), for 0<x<1`

But I don't know if it is possible to prove that this function is convex $f''(x)\geq 0$ for $0<x<1$. I've calculated the second derivative with [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) with this code

`d^2/dx^2 Harmonic(x)/Airy(x)`

> **Question.** Is it possible to prove that $$\frac{H_x}{\operatorname{Ai}(x)}\tag{1}$$ is a convex function for real numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$? **Many thanks.**

Comment: Tu poses des questions mais les réponses ne t'intéressent pas.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457660/does-converge-frac-sigman-pin-varphin-pin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica gives
$$f''(0)=\frac{\pi  \left(\pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2-4 \sqrt[6]{3} \zeta (3)\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} \approx -0.0162334,$$
and continuity implies that the second derivative remains negative near $x=0$. Thus $f$ is *not* convex over the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: Uff! What can I say now? Nothing. My thoughts is that the function was convex. Many thanks any case.

Comment: Uff, my thoughts was that the function was convex. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was a close call: Supporting user1337's computation, here is a graph of the second derivative on $[0, 0.002]$ is as follows:

$\hspace{6em}$ [image]

Comment: Many thanks also for this detail. My belief is that the function was convex for all $x\in(0,1)$.